# Sql query to pull top 3 records with max votes in each category

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Need some help with putting this query together. I'm using Mysql

I have two tables

### Video - contains videos uploaded by users

- video_id
- user_id
- category_id

### Vote - contains a vote given by any user for a particular video

- vote_id
- video_id
- user_id

I don't want to hardcode the categories in the query - the Categories are stored in the Category table which has category_id and category_name

I basically want a query that pulls the top 3 videos (ones with max votes) for each category.

Sample Data - Video Table

```
video_id |  user_id  | category_id
   1          100          10
   2          101          10
   3          102          11
   4          103          11
   5          104          11
   6          105          11
   7          105          12
```

Sample Data - Vote Table

```
vote_id  |  video_id |  user_id
  11           3          105
  12           3          102
  13           3          111
  14           3          121
  15           4          200
  16           4          201
  17           1          222
```

Sample Data - Category Table

```
category_id  |  category_name
   10               HipHop
   11               Rap
   12               Country
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I've added the sample data - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of problem that is trivial to solve with ranking functions. However, since MySQL does not yet support them, it makes it more difficult. In this design, I assumed that `video_id` was the primary key of the Video table.

```
Select video_id, user_id, category_id, vote_count, vote_rank
From    (
        Select VoteCounts.video_id, VoteCounts.user_id
            , VoteCounts.category_id, VoteCounts.vote_count
            , (
                Select Count(*) + 1
                From    (
                        Select V1.video_id, V1.user_id, V1.category_id
                            , Count(vote_id) As vote_count
                        From Videos As V1
                            Left Join Votes As V2
                                On V2.video_id = V1.video_id
                        Group By V1.video_id, V1.user_id, V1.category_id
                        )  As VoteCounts1
                Where VoteCounts1.category_id = VoteCounts.category_id
                    And (
                        VoteCounts1.vote_count > VoteCounts.vote_count
                        Or (VoteCounts1.vote_count = VoteCounts.vote_count
                            And VoteCounts1.video_id < VoteCounts.video_id )
                        )
                ) As vote_rank
        From    (
                Select V1.video_id, V1.user_id, V1.category_id
                    , Count(vote_id) As vote_count
                From Videos As V1
                    Left Join Votes As V2
                        On V2.video_id = V1.video_id
                Group By V1.video_id, V1.user_id, V1.category_id
                )  As VoteCounts
        ) As VoteRanks
Where VoteRanks.vote_rank <= 3
```

Comment: WOW - this query looks complicated - I tried it out but its not giving the right results - For example it category 4 - I have 4 videos with the following video_ids 4,5,6,7. Now video_id 4 has max vote and video_id 5 has least. So I would expect the query to return videos 4,6,7 but its returning 5,6,7. Similarly in another category instead of picking video_ids 2,8,10 - its picking 8,9,10 and leaving out video_id 2 which has the max votes - Thanks

Comment: The problem was say if there are 5 videos in a category, the video with the max votes gets assigned a vote_rank of 5 - but then at the bottom ur condition checks vote_rank <= 2 and hence the video with the max vote_rank was not getting selected

Comment: When I changed the line And Z1.vote_count < Z.vote_count to And Z1.vote_count > Z.vote_count - its working fine - but the moment we have 2 videos with the same vote_rank - it returns 4 videos instead of 3 - how can I handle that - and I'll also appreciate if you can explain the logic behind this query - Thanks man

Comment: If 2 or more videos have the same vote count, then we should probably just select the newer video based on the video_id or date stamp which is part of the video table - that way we dont assign the same vote_rank to them

Comment: @Gublooo - I've made a few corrections. The biggest correction is that I needed to reverse the sign when determining the vote rank. I.e., we need to find the how many other videos have more votes than the current one not less. I made the vote_rank 1 based instead of 0 based. I refactored the aliases to be a bit easier to read. Lastly, I included something to deal with ties. If two videos have the same votes, the query will treat the video with the lower video_id as having a higher rank.

Comment: @Thomas - thank you so much for helping me out - it works like a charm now -really appreciate you putting the time. Thanks a ton - I would have never figured that out on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MySQL, but here's how I would try to do it in SQL Server, and bringing perhaps some adjustments depending on the results which make sense.

```
select Category
        , Film
        , MAX(Votes) as Votes
    from (
        select TOP 3 c.category_name as Category
                , vd.video_id as Film
                , COUNT(vt.votes) as Votes
            from Category c
                inner join Video vd on vd.category_id = c.category_id
                inner join Votes vt on vt.video_id = vd.video_id
            where c.category_id = 10 -- HipHop
            group by c.category_name
                , vd.video_id
        union
        select TOP 3 c.category_name
                , vd.video_id
                , COUNT(vt.votes) as Votes
            from Category c
                inner join Video vd on vd.category_id = c.category_id
                inner join Votes vt on vt.video_id = vd.video_id
            where c.category_id = 11 -- Rap
            group by c.category_name
                , vd.video_id
        -- You need as much UNION as there are categories.
    ) Top3VotesPerCategory
    group by Category
        , Film
```

Depending whether you accepte downvotes on a film, one could register a negative vote a film, and this wouldn't mean that he recommends this video. If you do support such functional feature, then you might want to consider a conditional `SUM()`, instead of a `COUNT()`, for the number of votes, so that negative votes would be considered and would decrease its overall points in regards of votes.

Comment: Thanks Will - my knowledge in Sql is pretty basic - so I'm not sure how I would write this in Mysql as I'm sure TOP is not supported by Mysql still.

Comment: In MySQL you can use LIMIT 3 at the end of the query instead? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422488/select-first-10-distinct-rows-in-mysql