# Select first 10 distinct rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any way in MySQL to get the first 10 distinct rows of a table.

i.e. Something like...

```
SELECT TOP 10 distinct * 
FROM people 
WHERE names='SMITH'
ORDER BY names asc
```

However this method doesn't actually work, because it gives the error: "Syntax Error. Missing operator in query expression distinct *"

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT *
FROM    people
WHERE   names = 'Smith'
ORDER BY
        names
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: +1. Hi Quassnoi. I want to thank you for the great quality of your blog. I'm your fan. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE names ='SMITH'
ORDER BY names asc
limit 10
```

If you need add group by clause.
If you search Smith you would have to sort on something else.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `SELECT DISTINCT 10 * ...`

Comment: He's using MS SQL I thought? The issue is the ordering

Comment: That's what I put... SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 * [rest of sql]