# how do I select top 5 from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

right now I am using this really complex method for what I think could be a lot easier

```
<?php 
$a=0;
for($i=100; $i>=0; $i--){
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE likes=$i");
if($query){
$data= mysql_fetch_array($query);
$a++;
if($a<=5){
?><img id=a<?php echo $a; ?> src="img.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"/><?php
}
}
}
?>
```

by the way i have connected to the data base
what I want is to know the id of the images with the top likes
this will only work with up to 100 likes and if 2 have the same amount it also will not work 
is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm going to guess "MySQL"? In any case, searching for "select top from mysql" should yield lots of results (most will involved grouping or aggregates, as that is more fun, but the syntax for the limit should be quickly apparent; more so if a link to the manual was found first).

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422488/select-first-10-distinct-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Careful! `$i=' or '1'='1` boom!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can write your SQL so that it sorts and limits the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 5
```

Look more into MySQL select syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Next, you should not be using the mysql_ functions. They have been deprecated for a long time. Consider switching to mysqli_ or, better yet use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: ok. how do you access these in an array? since there will be 5 rows and not 1

Comment: Using PDO: `$statement = $pdo->prepare($query); while($row = $statement->fetchObject()) { echo $row->id; }`. Check the documentation for PDO and all will be clear.

Comment: @user2438604 You're already using `mysql_fetch_array()`, so that's how you *access* the rows.  Read the docs for more information or there are plenty of tutorials as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE likes=$i ORDER BY date_inserted DESC LIMIT 5);
```

Will work if you have a date or alternatively you can go by SERIAL descending if you have a serial primary key.

Comment: Good for pointing out that ORDER BY is required to ensure LIMIT is meaningful (otherwise the result could be any arbitrary records). Bad for using string interpolation still.